# Java: What is the unit of the difference of two System.currentTimeMillis?

Tags: java

What is the unit of the difference of two System.currentTimeMillis ?

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
longoperation();
elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

What is the unit of elapsed time here. It doesn't look like milliseconds.
Is the above code segment the right way to find the time taken to execute longoperation()?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't look like milliseconds'? The difference of two values in milliseconds is in milliseconds. The difference of two values in unit *X* is in *X*.

Comment: Well, it took some seconds to report that it is some 300ms!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is in milliseconds. Bear in mind that the difference is not absolutely correct and may vary.

Answer (score 4):

It is `ms` (MiliSecond) only, you are doing right.
You can ignore time taken while calculating millis

Answer (score 3):

It is milliseconds and your code looks correct.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you are doing is correct. If you want the time in seconds, simply divide it by 1000.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
longoperation();
long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, currentTimeMillis() returns you a milliseconds value.

On Windows, it used to be the case that the returned value had quite low resolution, and so was only accurate to something like 10ms. I'm not certain whether this is still the case as I haven't used Windows for a few years - but if your `longoperation()` actually takes just a few millis, and you're running on Windows, then you may see `elapsedTime` variously being 10ms or 0ms.

Comment: It's not just Windows.  Versions of UNIX / Linux do as well.